# How to make a new list of n occurrences based possible outcomes and frequencies?

Tags: python, for-loop, statistics

I apologize in advance, I really don't know how to explain what I'm asking for. I have a list of scores and a list of how frequently each score occurred and I want to make a new list with every occurrence.

I've been trying out some nested for loops, but the output iterates every score with every frequency.

```
for x in scores:
    for f in freq:
        for i in range(f):
            desired_output.append(x)
```

How would I make a new list to show all the outcomes?

```
scores = [6, 7, 8, 9]
frequency = [1, 3, 5, 4]

desired_output = [6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9,]
```

Comment: look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increase performance and reduce the number of iterations I would recommand in place of the second example by [toRex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5929910/torex):

```
scores = [6, 7, 8, 9]
frequency = [1, 3, 5, 4]

ls = []
for s,f in zip(scores,frequency):
  ls = ls + [s]*f;

print(ls)
```

Comment: This is more intuitive and works and is definitely more efficient with higher frequencies. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
scores = [6, 7, 8, 9]
frequency = [1, 3, 5, 4]
ls= [ [s]*f for s,f in zip(scores,frequency)]
print(ls)
```

Output

```
[[6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9, 9]]
```

If you want reduce the nested list to a single list then do follow the code below

```
from functools import reduce
scores = [6, 7, 8, 9]
frequency = [1, 3, 5, 4]

ls= [ [s]*f for s,f in zip(scores,frequency)]
single_ls=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,ls)

print(single_ls)
```

Comment: It took me a minute to understand applying a lambda to 2 variables, one being a list but it definitely works. thank you